# How to hide specific shares in the sidebar from Finder?

Tags: finder, sidebar

I want to hide some specific shares in the sidebar from Finder because I never access them and it get's confusing if everyone in my local network is online.

[image]

Is there a way to hide for example only the shares marked with the red arrow?

Comment: These are not Shared. They are mounted devices on your Mac.

Comment: 'Bautz' is mounted, the other ones definitely aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing is caring. Here's the solution to my 'problem'. Just go to `Finder -> Preferences -> Sidebar` and unclick the two points marked with the red arrows. From now on only the mounted shares will be listed in the sidebar of Finder. :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just drag the icon outside of the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the share to ".name" and it will be invisible in the Finder.